# .NET: Best practice for setting properties of main form from module

Tags: vb.net, forms, class, module, logic

I have a main form.
The logic of my application is huge. I have around 100 modules in my application.
In some modules I need to set some properties of the main form's controls.

I feel that calling something like

```
Public Module SomeStuff

    Public Sub DoSomething
      frmMain.MyControl.Location = ...
    End Sub

End Module
```

... is really dirty.

However, I can not move everything from the modules into the main form.

Is there any best practice to deal with such situation?

Edit: My code works, but it just feels ugly.

Thank you!

Comment: I would at least declare all functions like `DoSomething()` inside frmMain (if that's all they do). If you are using all modules and default form instances, I don't see much OOP, and that is why you may feel limited by your design at times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of options for setting properties on a form from a module, including:

- Passing an instance of the form or form controls to a module function to be set
- Returning the values from a module function to be set on the form

**Form as an argument**

The form or specific form controls could be passed as an argument to the module which sets the properties. This way you are not tied to a static instance of the form. However your functions may still be tightly coupled to the UI which may make them harder to unit test.

**Returning values**

To keep separation between the business logic and the UI, you could return the values that need to be applied to the form via a struct, class or dictionary. Then define a method or function to bind the values to the form controls.